# How can I convert a .sublime-syntax definition to a .tmGrammar.json file to use in VSCode(Monaco)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, grammar, monaco-editor, tmlanguage, sublime-syntax

I need to convert a `.sublime-syntax` definition to a `.tmGrammar.json` definition to use in VSCode. If this is possible then I would like to use it in an embedded Monaco Editor. The definition I'm trying to convert is for the [Charcoal ASCII sketching language](https://github.com/charcoal-lang/Charcoal). [This is the definition](https://github.com/charcoal-lang/Charcoal/blob/master/highlighters/Charcoal.sublime-syntax).

I tried searching around for a tool that could do this, but all I could find was [this Sublime Text feature](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev/wiki/Syntax-Definitions#converting-a-textmate-to-a-sublime-text-syntax-definition), that does the opposite. (I also don't have Sublime Text).

Comment: I have not found any tools that convert `.sublime-syntax` to anything else, including VSCode grammars. I've never come across the `.tmGrammar.json` format - from what I know of VSCode, it uses `.tmLanguage.json`.